# How do I have every test in class automatically tagged with a specific tag

Tags: scalatest

I am using the flatspec trait to create my tests and I would like to create a base class that would automatically tag any tests in that class with a particular tag.

For example, any tests in classes that inherit from the IntegrationTest class would automatically be appropriately tagged.  So instead of:

```
  class ExampleSpec extends FlatSpec {
      "The Scala language" must "add correctly" taggedAs(IntegrationTest) in {
      val sum = 1 + 1
      assert(sum === 2)
  }
```

I would like do this and still have the test tagged as an IntegrationTest

```
  class ExampleSpec extends IntegrationSpec {
      "The Scala language" must "add correctly" in {
      val sum = 1 + 1
      assert(sum === 2)
  }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're willing to use a direct annotation on the test class, rather than a parent class, you can use the example at https://github.com/kciesielski/tags-demo. Adapted somewhat for your example, you need to declare a Java class:

```
package tags;

import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.METHOD;
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.TYPE;
import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;

@org.scalatest.TagAnnotation
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({METHOD, TYPE})
public @interface MyAnnotation {
}
```

Then you use it to annotate the Scala test class:

```
@tags.MyAnnotation
class ExampleSpec extends FlatSpec {
  "The Scala language" must "add correctly" in {
  val sum = 1 + 1
  assert(sum === 2)
}
```

You then have to use the actual string `tags.MyAnnotation` to specify the tag you want run (or ignored).

I tried to annotate a parent class instead, but I can't get it to work. I could imagine it being a significant problem for you or not, depending on what else you're trying to do.

Actually, the online doc for the [org.scalatest.Tag](http://doc.scalatest.org/2.2.1/index.html#org.scalatest.Tag) class does a fair job of describing all this, although I say it *after* getting it to work by following the above project on GitHub..

Answer (score 4):

Since ScalaTest 2.2.0 tags can be inherited (http://www.scalatest.org/release_notes/2.2.0).

1. Add @Inherited to your annotation definition.

   ```
   package tags;

   import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
   import java.lang.annotation.Target;
   import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.METHOD;
   import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.TYPE;
   import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;

   **@Inherited**
   @org.scalatest.TagAnnotation
   @Retention(RUNTIME)
   @Target({METHOD, TYPE})
   public @interface RequiresIntegrationStuff {
   }
   ```
2. Annotate your base spec.

   ```
   @RequiresIntegrationStuff
   class IntegrationSpec extends FlatSpec {}
   ```
3. Just use your base spec as a base class.

   ```
   class ExampleSpec extends IntegrationSpec {
       "The Scala language" must "add correctly" in {
       val sum = 1 + 1
       assert(sum === 2)
   }
   ```

After that, ExampleSpec will be tagged as tags.RequiresIntegrationStuff.

You will find working project here: https://github.com/wojda/tags-demo (based on https://github.com/kciesielski/tags-demo from [Spiro Michaylov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27874143/3614835))